# Load image URL stored in HTML5 data tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, load

**Problem**

When user clicks on the thumbnail of an image, the image URL stored in HTML5 data attribute `data-url` should load, and the rest of the functionality should continue after. However, I don't know how to get the image to load with jQuery selectors.

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").on("click", function() {

        var url = $(this).data("url");

        $('<img data-url="">').load(function() {
            console.log("loaded");
            $("#wrapper").html('<img src="' + url + '">');
        });
    });
});
```

**Note** that the image that is loaded first is the thumbnail and when it is clicked, jQuery should wait until the image in `data-url` attribute has loaded. Once it's loaded, it should inject that image into `#wrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, find the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3Qss/) here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").on("click", function() {
        // grep the data attribute
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        if(url) {
            // if it is an url, create an image
            var img = $('<img />').appendTo('#Wrapper').hide();
            // set the src with the url
            img.attr("src", url);
            img.load(function() {    
                // if it is loaded, show the image
                // and do whatever you want.
                img.show();
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this

```
$('#img_id').click(function(){
    $("#wrapper").html('<img src="' + $(this).attr)('data-url') + '?' + new Date().getTime() + '">');
});
```